# Solving linear programming problem with global opt method

Tags: optimization, linear-programming

why not solve a linear programming problem with a global opt method, or a local search method as SQP or Newton methods? I am writting a solver facing linear and non linear problems, and I wonder whether it could be accurate to implement single optimization method that can crack all problems. Why not do so?

Thanks for your thoughts on this issue.

Comment: "Crack all problems..." Have you heard of NP-hard problems?

Answer (score 3):

What makes you think they aren't? Simplex algorithms are local search, and interior point methods are global optimisation.